# How to align div with proper space in between in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to align these 3 div with more margin?

i tried col-3, but still doesn't work for me, i want 1 div to be in left, 2nd in center, and 3rd in right. i tried using css for margin, but it's worse in responsive. do i need to do responsive part to?

Check this image, i want to make this..

[image: i want proper space in in between these 3 divs]

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>General Announcement</title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <section class="activities">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-primary text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-4">Upcoming activities for october 2019</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-sm-5">
                        <img src="images/img-5.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            <span class="d-block text-uppercase font-weight-bold mt-3">October 20</span>
                            <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Run for charity</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">More info</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-sm-5">
                        <img src="images/img-6.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <span class="d-block text-uppercase font-weight-bold mt-3">October 11</span>
                        <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Book drive</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">More info</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/img-7.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <span class="d-block text-uppercase font-weight-bold mt-3">October 21</span>
                        <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Recycling initiative</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">More info</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the col-12 header part outside of what is now your row and change row to be a flex column. BS4 supports flex and it's the best way to go for this use case.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/50e9n12p/3/)

```html
<section class="activities">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3 class="text-center text-primary text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-4">Upcoming activities for october 2019</h3>
                </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

                <div class="col-md-3 mb-sm-5">
                    <img src="images/img-5.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <span class="d-block text-uppercase font-weight-bold mt-3">October 20</span>
                        <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Run for charity</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">More info</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-sm-5">
                    <img src="images/img-6.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    <span class="d-block text-uppercase font-weight-bold mt-3">October 11</span>
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Book drive</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">More info</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="images/img-7.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    <span class="d-block text-uppercase font-weight-bold mt-3">October 21</span>
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Recycling initiative</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">More info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Hi, is there anyway with of doing it with col-md-4? with that space?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include **Bootstrap** css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>General Announcement</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <section class="activities">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3 class="text-center text-primary text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-4">Upcoming activities for
                        october 2019</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-sm-5">
                    <img src="images/img-5.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    <span class="d-block text-uppercase font-weight-bold mt-3">October 20</span>
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Run for charity</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">More info</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-sm-5">
                    <img src="images/img-6.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    <span class="d-block text-uppercase font-weight-bold mt-3">October 11</span>
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Book drive</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">More info</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="images/img-7.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    <span class="d-block text-uppercase font-weight-bold mt-3">October 21</span>
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Recycling initiative</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">More info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

try this I hope this will work :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, i am already using bootstrap CDN, i just didn't posted here..but i found my answer, however thanks for stopping by! :)